# Morse code translator help reading from file

Tags: java

Okay so I know there are other Morse code answers out there, but I have looked at many, but none of them worked. For my assignment I was to read a file, Morse.txt, into parallel arrays. Instead I just made two files, Morse.txt and Alphabet.txt one with code and the other with numbers and alphabet. I am supposed to use a class I made to do the translating part and when called in main it should translate user input. I can't seem to get this working. I've tried so many things from using a toString in the class or getter, but the return is not found when I put in the loop which I think has to be there(if that makes sense)..anyway here is my code for main:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class redo
{
    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
    {
        String line2, file2 = "Morse.txt";
        String line, file = "Alphabet.txt";

        File openFile = new File(file);
        File openFile2 = new File(file2);

        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(openFile);
        Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(openFile2);

        int index = 36;
        char[] charArray = new char[index]; 
        String[] code = new String[index];

        for(index = 0; index < 36; index++)
        {   
            while(inFile.hasNext())
            {
                    line = inFile.nextLine();
                    charArray = line.toCharArray();
                    //System.out.println(charArray[index]);
            }
        }       

        for(index = 0; index < 36; index++)
        {
            while(inFile2.hasNext())
            {
                code[index] = inFile2.nextLine();
                //System.out.println(code[index]);
            }
        }

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        String userInput;

        System.out.println("Enter something to translate: ");
        userInput= keyboard.nextLine();

        Translate inputTranslate = new Translate(userInput);

        inputTranslate.setInput(userInput);

        inputTranslate.setAlph(charArray);
        inputTranslate.setCode(code);

        inFile.close();
    }
}
```

and here is my class Translate(some things are commented out):

```
public class Translate
{
    String input;
    String code[];
    char alph[];

    public Translate(String input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public void setAlph(char[] alph)
    {
        this.alph = alph;
    }

    public void setCode(String[] code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getInput()
    {
        return input;
    }

//  public String getTranslate()
//  {
//      for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
//      {
//          for(int index = 0; index < alph.length; index++)
//          {
//              if(input.charAt(i) == alph[index])
//              {
//                  String output = code[index];
//              }
//          }
//      }
//      return output;
//  }


}
```

Morse.txt:

.----
..---
...--
....-
.....
-....
--...
---..

### ----.

.-
-...
-.-.
-..
.
..-.
--.
....
..
.---
-.-

### .-..

### -.

.--.
--.-
.-.

### ...

..-
...-
.--
-..-
-.--
--..

Alphabet.txt:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z

Comment: Please also add what are you writing in Morse.txt and Alphabet.txt

Comment: You haven't showed us the input, or at least a sample. Without that it's kind of hard to figure out what you're trying to do.  Also _"I can't seem to get this working"_ isn't enough of a problem statement.  Please edit your post to include the missing information.

Comment: If at all possible, post code that we can *actually run* (i.e. including all data) - this demonstrates the problem clearly, and we can also run and edit it locally to figure out what's wrong. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your return can't reach "output", you need to declare "output" above the loops and initialise it to output = null;

Even then it'll only send one string. So I did this;

```
public String getTranslate()
{
    String output = null;
    String[] translated = new String[input.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < alph.length; index++)
        {
            if(input.charAt(i) == alph[index])
            {
                output = code[index];
                translated[i] = output;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < translated.length; j++) {
        output = translated[0].concat(translated[j]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

This basically sticks all the codes together giving you your desired outcome.